# TYPO3 javascript footer with typoscript, WHERE clause breaks SELECT functionality

Tags: database, select, typo3, typoscript

I have a curious page structure, `colPos = 0` of the subpages is used as content for its parent ... these pages have animations that need code in the parent page footer so I added the field `tx_add_animation_code` in table `tt_content` and this code needs to be collected.

setup.txt:

```
# footer script
page.footerData {
    # collect subpages
    5 = LOAD_REGISTER
    5 {
        pageIds.cObject = CONTENT
        pageIds.cObject {
            table = pages
            select {
                pidInList = this
                recursive = 0
                selectFields = uid
                where = {#no_search}=0
            }
            renderObj = TEXT
            renderObj {
                field = uid
                required = 1
                wrap = |,
            }
        }
    }
    # open javascript
    10 = TEXT
    10.value (
        <script type="text/javascript">

    )
    # test id collection
    25 = TEXT
    25 {
        data = register:pageIds
        noTrimWrap (
|
/* subpage Ids: | */
|
        )
    }
    # collect animation code from CE's on subpages
    20 = CONTENT
    20 {
        table = tt_content
        select {
            pidInList.data = register:pageIds
            # THIS LINE BREAKS FUNCTIONALITY
            where = {#colPos}=0
        }
        renderObj = COA
        renderObj {
            10 = TEXT
            10.stdWrap.field = tx_add_animation_code
        }
        if {
            value = pagets__homepage,pagets__onepage
            isInList.data = TSFE:page|backend_layout
        }
    }
    # close javascript
    30 = TEXT
    30.value (

        </script>
    )
    90 = RESTORE_REGISTER
}
```

`where = {#colPos}=0` breaks the functionality, and if I do not include it, of course, the field is collected from all the content elements ...

what is the issue ?

Comment: do you get an error message or an invalid query you can show us? I would assume the resulting query might show `... WHERE col_pos = 0 ...`

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ, no error message, but I did not setup TYPO3 to yield them, just no autput... I think the where as I formulated should go since it works in the first instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that there are really some Content Elements on the Subpages having colPos=0. Please note that some extensions like gridelements or other multicol extensions will set the colPos of their childelements to something negative like -67 so they won't match the select-statement anymore.